# Cheap, modern tape backup drive?

Tags: backup

Can someone suggest a cheap backup drive that holds maybe 1 tape for backups, is still sold, still popular, and is likely to still be accessible on it or another model in another 10 years?

Comment: And don't give me none of that "but those are obsolete", I'm not having that; tapes are still cheaper than hdds per GB.

Comment: Here is a search result on [newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007545&IsNodeId=1&Description=tape%20drives&name=Backup%20Drives&Order=BESTMATCH&isdeptsrh=1) for backup drives.

If you are really looking for "cheap" drives, you might try ebay, or local thrift shops, though they can be a crapshoot.

Comment: When it comes to tape drives, "cheap" basically means buying at least two generations old off Ebay, and "still accessible" means Ultrium/LTO: you'll be writing to LTO-5 tape on a used LTO-5 drive today, and reading it from a used LTO-7 drive ten years from now.

Comment: His comment on tapes being cheaper than HDD may not be as true as he thinks it is lol.

Comment: @NZKshatriya, it depends on the data volume.  Per-terabyte, LTO-5 costs about half of what hard drives do (LTO-6 is the current sweet spot, at a third the price).  Thing is, the break-even point for a $2000 LTO-5 drive is around 100 TB of data.

Comment: @mark Yeah, a $2k drive places the medium out of range for most consumers.  And you also have to take into account the environmental storage requirements for magnetic tape.  Can't just toss them in the attic here in south Texas, unless you want to risk a nice melted glob in the summer lol.   Reminds me, I need to keep reminding parents to move old family Christmas VHS tapes to digital...they keep putting it off.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify a price range, but your use of the word "cheap" implies you looked at what's commercially available and were shocked by the fact that even low-end tape drives run around $2000.

I'd recommend getting a secondhand Quantum TC-L52AN (internal drive) or TC-L52BN (the same thing, in an external enclosure).  I don't have experience with this particular model, but I've had good luck with Quantum tape drives in the past.  They run around $500-$800 on Ebay; you'll probably need a SAS controller card as well, but those can be found for under $100.  The LTO standard requires two generations of backward compatibility, so the current LTO-7 drives can read the TC-L52AN's LTO-5 tapes.  Ten years from now, you'll be able to get a secondhand LTO-7 drive to read your tapes.

Comment: Also, I think that is why he likely has not been back since posting.....sticker shock coma.